# Beacon detection using smart watch

Tags: wear-os, apple-watch, beacon, estimote

I am newly started work on beacon. Can you tell me one things, is it possible beacon detect from watch without phone? Which smart watch, its possible?

Answer (score 4):

Apple Watch's watch OS doesn't expose the necessary iBeacon or Bluetooth LE APIs that'd allow it detect beacons without phone's assistance. The only way for now is to do the scanning on the iPhone, and relay the scan results to your Watch app.

Android Wear on the other hand exposes the same Bluetooth LE API that a regular Android does[1]. Which means that, if the watch itself supports BLE scanning (I'd assume most of them do), you can use the *android.bluetooth.le* API[2] to detect beacons without phone's assistance.

---

[1] Well, for most intents and purposes, Android Wear *is* just a regular Android.

[2] Or any beacon library that utilizes this API, so that you don't have to write all the beacon discovery and parsing yourself. [Android Beacon Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) is probably the most widely used one. Since you tagged your question `estimote`, I assume you have Estimote Beacons—if that's correct, then [Estimote Android SDK](https://github.com/estimote/android-sdk) should also work for you. Note: I haven't tested either of the SDKs with Android Wear, so can't confirm 100% they'll work.

Comment: Really appreciate for your quick reply. Can you please share some code snippets?

Comment: On Android, you can just follow any regular beacon detection tutorials—e.g., for Estimote SDK: http://developer.estimote.com/android/tutorial/part-1-setting-up/

Comment: Its working fine for phone. So we can use same code for watch? Mean same delegate method to tract the beacon.

Comment: Yup, the same code should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using Estimote Beacons with their SDK and an Android smartwatch to develop my app.
I had some issues with Android Wear, because the smartwatch reads the signal from the beacons every 5 seconds despite having set on my app much shorter intervals (on the smartphone I had no problem). In my case this represents a major problem.
I hope to have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with Android Wear (with just some limitations) and turns out not possible with Apple Watch. See this experiment http://elekslabs.com/2015/09/nearables-wearables-connecting-beacons-with-smartwatches.html